# ensemble results from different classifier in R

Tags: r, ensemble-learning

I have prediction of my data in different classifier. I would like to ensemble the results of them in order to get better final result. Is it possible in R?
lets say:

```
SVMpredict=[1 0 0 1...]
RFpredict=[1 1 0 1 ...]
NNpredict=[0 0 0 1 ...]
```

is it possible to combine results by any ensemble technique in R?how?
thanks

Edited:
I run my classifiers on different samples (my case DNA chromosomes). In some samples SVM works better than the others like RF. I want a technique to ensemble the results by considering which classifier works better.
for example if i take average of output probabilities and round them, it would be considered as all classifier are equal effective in result. but when SVM worked better, we should consider results for SVM (with 86% accuracy) has 60% importance and 25% (72% accuracy) for RF and 15% NN (64% accuracy). (these numbers are just examples for clarification)
is there anyway that I can do that?

Comment: Though I haven't tested, you may find the following package useful - https://github.com/zachmayer/caretEnsemble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the structure of the output of Your classifier.
If it is {0,1} outcome, as You provided, You can just make mean of the predictions and then average it and round it:

```
round((SVMpredict+RFpredict+NNpredict)/3)
```

If You know performance of the classifiers, weighted mean is a good idea - favor the ones that perform better. Hardcore apporach is to optimize weights via `optim` function.

If You know class probabilites for each prediction, it is better average them instead of letting them just vote ({0,1} output case above).

Comment: thanks for relying. Averaging probabilities is a good way if they are all equal effective is in prediction. what if SVM predicted better in some cases. it should be considered as more important probabilities. (I edited my question). thanks again.

Comment: If Your output are probabilities, You can just do `0.6 * SVMpredict + 0.25 *  RFpredict + 0.15 * NNpredict`. The challenge is how to find the best coefficients. Set up a validation set and adjust the coefficient to maximize performance on it (method called stacking). You could do this manually or using `optim` function.